# Definition of analyticity in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, analyticity, analytic-functions

In my complex analysis class, I learned that a complex function $f(z)$ is said to be analytic at $z_0$ if there is a neighborhood around $z_0$ in which $f$ is differentiable. Then, I learned various properties of analytic functions, but I never quite understood why the notion of pointwise differentiability is not enough and we in fact need differentiability "in nearby neighborhoods".

What is the importance/role of "neighborhoods" in this context? What goes wrong if one replaces analyticity with differentiability? I thought that when one talks about pointwise differentiability, one would like to work in open sets and since analyticity and differentiablity are the same in open sets, I do not see what is important about defining analyticity the way it is defined

Comment: It's a contraction of language: instead of saying "analytic on a neighborhood of $z_0$" all the time, we declare the shorter phrase "analytic at $z_0$" to have that broader meaning. The notion of a derivative is a natural pointwise concept, so saying "differentiable at $z_0$" already means something and thus is not available as a term to describe behavior in an open set around $z_0$. The function $f(z) = z|z|$ is differentiable at the origin ($f(h)/h \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathbf C$), but is not expressible as a complex power series on a neighborhood of the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Because while the definition "differentiable in a neighborhood" is a suitably-*equivalent* way of saying "analytic" in the context of *complex* analysis, it is not necessarily the most *informative* way.

The most informative definition of analytic is just the extension of the one from real analysis: a complex $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ *iff its Taylor series expansion at $z_0$ converges to $f(z)$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$*.

In *complex* analysis, this is *equivalent* to the statement that it be differentiable in a neighborhood. In real analysis, it is not equivalent.

In fact, in complex analysis the following *equivalences* hold: all (complex-)differentiable functions are (complex-)smooth and all smooth functions are analytic. But the *definitions* of these terms need not be the same, even though we *could do so* because of these equivalences. IMO, it's better to use the regular definitions and then *prove* the equivalence as a useful theorem. To go from Real to Complex with a change of definition of "analytic" from "converging Taylor series" to "differentiable in a neighborhood" would be rather jarring, and leave one scratching one's head for reasons, imo. And it obscures some of the beauty, which is precisely that in the complex plane the added structure is far more restrictive on the behavior of the function than in real-number analysis and the reasons for it being so (essentially, that a function which is locally complex-linear (and non-constant) preserves the shape of vanishing objects at (almost) every point, while more general 2D real $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ functions do not.).

Comment: So, there is a real analytic function which is differentiable only at the point of expansion, and equals to its Taylor series, yet it is not differentiable in a neighborhood?

Comment: @momonao: The Taylor series must converge in a neighborhood to the function, this implies the function will be differentiable at other points than just the point of expansion. Any Taylor series will converge _at_ its point of expansion, of course.

Comment: Then, what do you mean by "in real analysis, it is not"?

Comment: @momonao: Ah. I see. Not equivalent, that is (to being differentiable in a neighborhood).

Comment: Is one stronger than the other? or how are they related? I mean, in real analytic setting

Comment: @momonao: "Complex analytic" is stronger than real-differentiable in that complex-analytic implies real-differentiable but not the other way around. Real differentiable could mean either the restriction to real axis is differentiable, or that we can find the Fréchet derivative (the thing given by the Jacobian, when it makes sense.).